# Run a welcome tour after multisite creation?

Tags: customization

I just found this amazing piece of code that I really wish is still working on the latest versions of Wordpress. https://gist.github.com/DevinWalker/7595475

It should run a "tour" when the theme is first activated. But I am having trouble. I want it to run this tour when a new multisite is created and the user logins for the first time.

This is the code for running when the theme is activated:

```
if( current_user_can('basic') || current_user_can('premium') && isset($_GET['activated']) && 'themes.php' == $GLOBALS['pagenow'] || $_GET['welcome_tour']) {
    require get_template_directory() . '/inc/theme-tour.php';
}
```

How can I redo this to activate when a new multisite is created and first logged into the dashboard?

Thank you!

Comment: `current_user_can('premium')` is that and `basic` a role added by the theme?

Comment: That is created by me, two user roles named that way.